# Why am I seeing Diddy Kong's face everywhere?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing-ds

On various tracks, I see  pictures of Diddy Kong - they are framed, and everything.

[image]

Do they serve any purpose? Or are they just everywhere because, well, the game is named after him? It seems a little strange, and it looks like I should be able to interact with them somehow, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

They're just decoration. Faces of other characters appear in-game as well.

---

Large faces

The faces of some of the characters (Pipsy, Bumper, Krunch) appear
Wizpig-style on an icy cliff-face in Snowball Valley. Just before you go
through to the snowball run of the level's title, look to the side to
see the faces.
These are also featured briefly in the ending sequence.

---

See [This FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/197118-diddy-kong-racing/faqs/3189) on Gamefaqs (Quoted above). It doesn't mention the pictures of Diddy specifically, but it does point out little-known interactions and graphics.

Some of the decorative graphics do serve a purpose though, such as the billboard by the lighthouse.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an image here? Or is it a block quote?

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do directly with the faces I am seeing - the large faces you mention are in the game, but they are not the ones that I mean.

Comment: I'm using it as an example of decorative faces. Having played the game all the way through I know the paintings have no function. If you had read the FAQ, which outlines unknown and hidden functions/features, you would have realized that the paintings aren't mentioned. Hence you have two sources (me and the FAQ) instead of just me.

Comment: I read the FAQ. Just because it doesn't mention the faces I mean doesn't automatically mean anything.

Comment: You're absolutely correct! But it can be used as evidence. If its not enough for you, that's perfectly okay.